# Special Characters (German Umlauts) in Blazor manifest.json?

Tags: json, visual-studio-2019, blazor, microsoft-teams

so I want to create a Microsoft Teams App using Visual Studio 2019, Teams Toolkit and Blazor, and I'm having a hard time getting Unicode Characters (German Umlaute ä, ö, and ü) to show up in my manifest.json - or rather in the Teams App Description page. I'm also pretty new at developing with Blazor and JSON.

I've tried the HTML-style `&ouml;` but this just gets passed right through.
I've tried the "\u00f6" but then it just shows up as "?".

How do i get Unicode characters into my manifest? Anything I'm missing? Do I have to switch to a different encoding? Where do I even see what type of encoding is being used?

manifest.json:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/json-schemas/teams/v1.9/MicrosoftTeams.schema.json",
  "manifestVersion": "1.9",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "localizationInfo": {
    "defaultLanguageTag": "de"
  },
  "developer": {
    "name": "Römer R\u00f6mer",
...
```

is displayed as:

[image: Created by: R?mer R?mer]

Any suggestions of what I'm missing?

**EDIT**
So as a few answers have suggested, I've tried saving the manifest.json in a different encoding (ANSI, UTF-8) but nothing works. It seems to me that Microsoft Teams is somehow not interpreting the manifest correctly. Which is weird, because the Description Page of some other apps include Umlauts and they are displayed correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We are able to repro the issue. We have raised a bug for this issue, concerned engineering team is working on it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Notepad++ to check and also change the encoding of a text file.

https://notepad-plus-plus.org/downloads/

As a developer from Austria, who also has to fight with umlauts, I would recommend to change the encoding of the file.

You can change the encoding in Notepad++: Menu bar -> encoding/

**EDIT:** But by the way, I think that umlauts and special characters etc. should not be used in manifest files or source code files.

Comment: Why do you think umlauts should not be used? It includes the developer's name an a description of the app. Since we are coding for a German-speaking environment, it is clear, that the description will have to use umlauts. It's still 2021 and not 1995 ;)

Comment: Btw, the notepad++ setting only changes the way notepad++ interprets the file. That's why I asked where to see the encoding of the file. Usually it's declared at the beginning of a file like the HTML-style ```<meta charset="UTF-8">```

Comment: I think you should rather try to avoid umlauts etc. as variable names etc., I personally made  bad experiences with umlauts in this usage.

Comment: The encoding of the text file is not only a matter of interpretation. Depending on which encoding is set for the text file in NP++, umlauts and some special characters are stored differently.

I would try the following: Open file -> change encoding to UTF-8 -> type the umlauts -> save.

Comment: Wait, I DON'T want to use umlauts as variable names. Everything in code (which the user doesn't see) I don't use umlauts. But this is about a string that is presented to the user, so there should of course be umlauts in it. Otherwise it's a bad user experience

Comment: Unfortunately the different encoding didn't change anything :( It's still presented as "?"

Comment: In any case, it should be possible somehow. In the Teams app library, apps with umlauts at "Erstellt von"/"Created by" can be found. (for ex. Timeghost)

Answer (score 1):

In VS you can use File/Save {your file} As...

then select to change the encoding in the drop down for the Save button

[image]

[The docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/resources/troubleshoot#error-while-reading-manifestjson) say UTF-8 without BOM

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately it was already saved with that encoding :( I'm starting to think that it is not a Blazor/JSON issue but rather how Microsoft Teams handles the manifest....

Comment: Ah yes, the teams docs suggest you should select UTF-8 encoding - try that maybe

Comment: Tried that as well - but to no avail